# C#: JSON One to Many Data Parse - SSIS Script Component

Tags: c#, json, ssis

Any help would be appreciated. I am trying to parse data from a JSON source file in SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services). I can parse through the data but am getting stuck on parsing the data where there is a 'one to many' relationship. There is a data entity repeated several times ("display_k") -

```
"responses":
[
{"display_k":"good","answer":null}
,{"display_k":"bad","answer":null}
,{"display_k":"general","answer":"The whole process was Easy. "}
,{"display_k":"would_buy_again","answer":true}
,{"display_k":"happy_with_customer_service","answer":null}
]
```

The full code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using System.IO;
//using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        var filePath = Connections.Connection.AcquireConnection(null).ToString();
        using (var fileContents = new StreamReader(filePath))

            while (fileContents.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                var record = fileContents.ReadLine();

                var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
                var memStream = new MemoryStream(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(record));
                var root = ser.ReadObject(memStream) as RootObject;

                //reviewables
                var CustomerExperienceReview = root.customer_experience_reviews;
                foreach (var CER in CustomerExperienceReview)
                {
                    OutputBuffer.AddRow();

                    OutputBuffer.id = CER.id;
                    OutputBuffer.branchattribution = CER.branch_attribution;
                    OutputBuffer.reviewerfirstname = CER.reviewer.first_name;
                    OutputBuffer.reviewerid = CER.reviewer.id;
```

// Cannot get the output buffer to  show the correct result:

```
OutputBuffer.responsesdisplaykey = string.Join(",", CER.responses.display_key);
                }
            }
    }

    public class Pagination
    {
        public int total_entries { get; set; }
        public int current_page { get; set; }
        public int total_pages { get; set; }
        public int per_page { get; set; }
        public object previous_page { get; set; }
        public int next_page { get; set; }
    }

    public class Summary
    {
        public Pagination pagination { get; set; }
        public int moving_window_size { get; set; }
        public SortOrder sort_order { get; set; }
        public List<object> sort_orders { get; set; }
    }

    public class Reviewer
    {
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Respons
    {
        public string display_key { get; set; }
        public object answer { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomerExperienceReview
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string branch_attribution { get; set; }
        public List<Respons> responses { get; set; }


    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Summary summary { get; set; }
        public List<CustomerExperienceReview> customer_experience_reviews { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
OutputBuffer.responsesdisplaykey = string.Join(",", CER.responses.display_key);
```

Based on the class definitions, CER.responses is a List<Respons>.  If you want a comma-separated list of display keys, you'll need to project the Respons objects to strings.

```
OutputBuffer.responsesdisplaykey = string.Join(",", CER.responses.Select(r=>r.display_key));
```

Comment: Hi Chris thank you for your reply. I am getting the following error message:Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ScriptMain.Respons>' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ScriptMain.Respons>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I have added using System.Linc

I am getting the display_key ... any advice on how I can get the valaues for "answer" as well please?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: please ignore my last comment. My lack of confidence in C-sharp scripting. I have got it working:
OutputBuffer.responsesdisplaykey = string.Join(",", CER.responses.Select(r => r.display_key + ":" + r.answer));

Comment: Sorry for not checking in sooner.  I'm glad you've got it worked out.